# Is this possible to use migrations with bookshelf.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am trying to use migrations with knex and bookshelf, and so far thats my code, it is an example from the bookshelf documentation:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('books', function(table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('name');
  }).createTable('summaries', function(table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('details');
    table.integer('book_id').unique().references('books.id');
  });
};
```

I tried run:

```
knex migrate:make my_migration_name
knex migrate:latest
knex migrate:rollback
```

But not a single change in my database. Any ideas how I can get it working?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.then()` to create a chain of promises:

```js
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('books', function(table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('name');
  }).then(function() {
    return createTable('summaries', function(table) {
      table.increments('id').primary();
      table.string('details');
      table.integer('book_id').unique().references('books.id');
    });
  });
};
```